# When creating a bash array using mapfile and parallel, why isn't the array created when used inside a function?

Tags: bash

When I use `mapfile` with `parallel` to create an array inside a function the array isn't created properly.

Why is this?

#### Array creation not in function

```bash
mapfile -t arr < <(parallel -j 0 echo ::: {1..5})  

declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="4" [4]="5")
```

#### Same thing but inside a function

```bash
mapRay() { mapfile -t "$1" < <(parallel -j 0 "$2" ::: "$3"); }

mapRay arr echo {1..2}

declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="1")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why is this?

```bash
$ cat un714227.sh
mapRay(){ mapfile -t "$1" < <(parallel -j 0 "$2" ::: "$3"); }
mapRay arr echo {1..2}
$ bash -x ./un714227.sh
++ mapRay arr echo 1 2
++ mapfile -t arr
+++ parallel -j 0 echo ::: 1
```

As you see, `mapRay` is invoked with $1=arr $2=echo $3=1 $4=2 and `parallel -j0 "$2" ::: "$3"` runs `echo` with argument `1` only, ignoring the `2`.

The array correctly contains the output of the `parallel` command; it is the input to the `parallel` command that wasn't what you apparently wanted.

You probably want something like `"${@:3}"` to get *all* arguments after the first 2.

Alternatively, a classic way to handle special (sometimes optional) then homogenous but varying args is to handle the special args and `shift` them out, then handle [the rest](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10346/why-did-the-gilligans-island-theme-song-change-between-seasons):

```
mapRay(){
  local var="$1" cmd="$2"
  shift 2
  mapfile -t "$var" < <(parallel -j0 "$cmd" ::: "$@")
}
```

Comment: ahhh of course… I’m such an idiot, should’ve used `$@`, thanks a lot, I tried using  `set -x` but it didn’t show anything, thanks for `-x` as well

Comment: for your 2nd code, what’s the use case, and why would you need to do it in a certain case, I read your explanation but I’m dense, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: actually `set -x‘`and  `x` do the same thing I must just have not seen it when I used `set -x` to the guy who made the edit saying ‘that’s specific to bash not sh’ well this is a `bash` question not a `sh` question so there was no need in that

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas you made an edit or comment saying that’’s specific to ‘bash` not `sh` well this is a `bash` question not a `sh` question so there was no need in that

Comment: @ikkachu can you revert the change by @StéphaneChazelas, this is not a `sh` question, `bash` syntax should be used and this should be obvious as `mapfile` is a bash thing

Comment: for some reason I get no output when using either `set -x` or `bash -x` anyone help? I’m on mac but usually `set -x` always gives an output

Comment: @Nikotine, the code initially had `./un714227.sh` with `./un714227.sh` without shebang, which means it's meant to be interpreted by `sh`. `mapfile` is a bash feature, so does not being in a sh script. Running `bash -x ./un714227.sh` to make sure `bash` is used to interpret that bash script is more correct. Alternatively, we could have added a `#! /bin/bash -x` shebang.

Comment: In any case `set -x; bash un714227.sh` as in your suggested edit (which I've rejected) would be wrong as it sets the xtrace option for the wrong shell (not the one interpreting `un714227.sh`). You also *want* the `./` prefix to make sure bash doesn't fall backup to looking up the script in `$PATH` if it can't find it in the current working directory.

Comment: if you run the script with `bash` doesn’t it run through bash regardless of the shebang? Using `sh` stuff in a bash script is an error on the part of the commentator so can’t you just edit the sh parts out of his script? That would make more sense. Alternatively, you could have `set -x` inside the top of the function and `set +x` at the bottom of the function

Comment: in your comment I thought you were saying the syntax should be `sh` not `bash` as I didn’t know the commentator was using `sh` stuff in a bash script. Are you saying it’s necessary to have a bash shebang or that if there is no shebang the script will be interpreted by `sh` despite it being run as `bash shebangless.sh`?

Comment: yes that is what you’re saying if I understand your edit correctly now that if there is no  bash shebang the script will run through `sh` but I have read and thought that once you run the script as `bash shebangless.sh` it runs through bash. Is this an error?

Comment: nevermind your edit is correct, it’s just the wording of the edit comment which confused me

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at `parset` (https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parset.html)

```
parset myarray seq 3 ::: 4 5 6
echo "${myarray[1]}"
```

Or in your case:

```
parset arr -j0 echo ::: {1..2}
echo "${arr[1]}"
```

It will also handle if the output from each job is multiple lines.

Comment: this seems like more hassle than my `parallel` version, my one automatically echos the input, what’s the advantage to `parset`? does it create an array? so would eliminate the need for me using `mapfile`?

Comment: yes I think `parset` allows you to create an array from the function and inputs you give it, many thanks, I’ll be using this now.